# Why doesnt visual studio add chained references?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have just added a reference to one of our own Dlls when I tried to use It I couldnt because of a missing dll that the new one references.

Whats the deal? When you add a reference should all the chained dlls that it references be added to? (apart from those in the GAC)...?

Comment: This can be nice feature request from Microsoft.. but as things stands this is "by design" behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, it is pain when you have complex inter dependencies between projects or even worse when you have between solutions.

when it is between projects, you can mark (Copy Local to true to make sure any dependency that project A depends gets dropped to its build folder.

Visual Studio doesnt handle chained dependencies. you have to do it yourself (either by script or some sort of dependency build tools)

Comment: Really? I did not know that thought I would have noticed that by now... Thanks

Comment: yeah, we use our own tool to build up the dependency tree and resolve it (i.e. copy to build folder) as part of the solution build

Comment: kind of, we use dependency injection along with our own custom tool to build up the tree. as Matt mentioned, better to try NuGet, we have seen the demo of it, it is quite handy

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled automatically with a package manager addin such as [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/)

Comment: that's the one! we saw the demo of it, and I tried to remember its name. we were planning to use it